# orderBy filter not working in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-orderby

I am using orderby filter to sort rate of my product.But it is not working properly.Please help me to find out the issue. 
Json :

productSize  :: [{"prodsize":"DOUBLE","sizerate":"181.00"},{"prodsize":"FAMILY","sizerate":"316.00"},{"prodsize":"SOLO","sizerate":"79.00"}]

Code :

```
<div class="item" style="border: 0px; padding: 7px"
        ng-repeat="size in productSize  | orderBy:'sizerate'">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col" style="margin-top: 20px">{{size.prodsize}}</div>
            <div class="col" style="text-align: right">
                Rs.{{size.sizerate}} <label class="checkbox" style="top: 16px"><input value="true"
                    name="size" type="radio" ng-model="sizeChecked" ng-change="addPropertiesToProduct('Size',size.prodsize,size.sizerate,sizeChecked)"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `orderBy` filter is working. Your problem comes from the fact that the `sizerate` properties are strings instead of numbers, therefore:

```
"181.00" < "316.00" < "79.00"
```

Correct your data structure to get the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your json like this,

```
[{"prodsize":"DOUBLE","sizerate":181.00},{"prodsize":"FAMILY","sizerate":316.00},{"prodsize":"SOLO","sizerate":79.00}]
```

Working [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/cf945br1/)